# How to create a treeview like structure in Nstableview for OSX?

Tags: macos

How do I show two records in columns for a nstableview. When clicking on each row I want to expand the nstableview and show some more records under that selected row like a tree view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is so broad I can only give a broad answer: in Cocoa, what you call a "tree view" is known as an outline view. You can use [`NSOutlineView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOutlineView_Class/index.html) to implement it. See the [Outline View Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OutlineView/OutlineView.html).